# Cant install missing packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

When running `sudo apt -qq update` the terminal gives me this:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libphonon4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-declarative : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libqt4-network : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libqt4-opengl : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libqt4-script : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libqt4-sql : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libqt4-sql-sqlite : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libqt4-xml : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libqt4-xmlpatterns : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libqtdbus4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libqtgui4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 musique : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
 phonon-backend-gstreamer : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.1) but it is not installed
 qdbus : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 qt-at-spi : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8~) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

And when I run `sudo apt-get install -f` to install the missing packages it gives me this:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libqtcore4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqtcore4
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
17 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1 552 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5 092 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 234467 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqtcore4:amd64 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf', which is different from other instances of package libqtcore4:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: What source are you getting libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb from? In the Ubuntu repos, the deb has a slightly different name. The difference is causing your problem.

Comment: I have no idea honestly, im running Gallium OS and im using their built in software updater, still very new to Linux.
 How do I change sources?